# How to get Facebook Friends Age in Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am writing an app in which i am **fetching list of facebook friends along with their names, profile pics and birthdays**, to get that i am using below query:

```
String query = "SELECT name, birthday, uid, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

and i have given these **permissions**:

```
String[] facebook_permissions = { "user_photos", "user_birthday",
        "friends_birthday", "friends_photos", "read_stream",
        "offline_access" };
```

but now i also **want to show Age** of my facebook friend, and i guess to get that i should use

```
  age_range
```

I am also trying to get age of facebook friends by using below query but i am **getting null in place of age**:

```
     String query = "SELECT name, birthday, uid, pic_square, age_range FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

Answer (score 2):

Age range is not how old is a person, but, as [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) says:

> containing min and max for the age range; Possible age ranges are
>   13-17, 18-20, and 21+; max is not set if the age is 21+

Why don't you calculate how old friends are using birthday and today dates? This can be done in a very simple way using native Calendar.

I'd recommend you to use new facebook API too.