# How to get age range(age_range) information using facebook-android-sdk.jar in android

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I integrated facebook jar (`facebook-android-sdk.jar`) into my project. I am getting all information about user (email, firstname, lastname, work, etc).  But I am unable to get age_range.

Can any one give small example. Thanks in advance.

I am authorizing like this:

```
mFacebook.authorize(activity, new String[] {
        "read_stream", "email","user_birthday"}, 
    new LoginDialogListener());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Facebook Friends Age in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377511/how-to-get-facebook-friends-age-in-android)